# Binding params with Raw Query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a query for a paginated listing page. Some part of the **SELECT** and **WHERE** parts are raw queries. To avoid sql vularabilities, I need to use parameter binding for this query. It is worked fine for **WhereRaw** query but not worked in **SELECT** section.

Please see my query here:

```
$aJob  = JobKeywords::where('job_keywords.status', 1)
                        ->where('job_keywords.expiry_date', '>=', $today);
           whereRaw('MATCH(job_title,company_name,skills) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0', [$keyword])
      ->select([DB::Raw('job_keywords.job_id as job_id, ? as candidate_id, 1 as fts_search', [$candidateId]),"job_keywords.location as job_location_name",
        DB::raw('MATCH(job_title,company_name,skills) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score', [$keyword]),
        "job_keywords.company_name",
        "job_keywords.job_id as id","job_keywords.job_title",
         "job_keywords.skills",
         "job_keywords.expiry_date",
        "job_keywords.monthly_salary_range_min","job_keywords.monthly_salary_range_max",
        'job_keywords.min_experience_in_year',
        'job_keywords.metadata'])
->orderBy('score', 'DESC')
->paginate(10);
```

The parameter binding in `WhereRaw` is working fine but inside `Select(DB::Raw)` not working. It will throw `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number error`. If we debug `print_r($aJob->toSql()) and print_r($aJob->getBindings())` then you can see the parameter `inside DB::raw` is not counted.

Do any one have any idea about this?

Comment: eagerly waiting for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects)

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')
   ->selectRaw('price * ? as price_with_tax', [1.0825])
   ->get();`
```

Comment: Happy it helped you :)